# Uncaught LogicException: byID can't be called on an UnsavedRelationList

Tags: silverstripe, modeladmin

I am creating a model_admin menu to manage orders. The 'Order' data object has a *Has-Many* relationship to 'Package' and the 'Package' has a *Has-Many* relationship to 'Product'. 
I am using gridfield relation editor in Order and Package to add/link new 'Package' and 'Product'. So basically the process is to click on 'Add Order' then click on 'Add Package' then click on 'Add Product' and then fill in the product information.

Until this point, everything works fine, but when I entered all the product fields and clicked on create an error 'Uncaught LogicException: byID can't be called on an UnsavedRelationList' is thrown. 
I understand this is because the 'Package' and 'Order' has not been created so it can not associate the products with them.

Of course I can create the Order first, then create the package, then add the 'Product', then everything works fine. However this is not intuitive and it is supposed to add products to packages and then create orders. I don't know if there is any way to implement my requirement, or if using gridfields within model_admin form is not the right solution for this.

Looking forward to any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: can you see from tracelog if this error is caused by your own code (e.g. in a getter method in your order or product DO) or generally by modeladmin / silverstripe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that you're trying to do something to a has-many or many-to-many relationship before the core record is saved. Check you onBeforeWrite handlers. I often find it's helpful to hide the gridfields for related lists if `$this->isInDB()` is false.

Comment: yes you are exactly right because when I add a new 'Product', the 'Package' has not been created and same for the 'Order', but would there be a way to add 'Products' first and link them to Package and then link the Packages to the Order, I need all done within one ModelAdmin interface instead of separating them, I think this provides better user experience. Not sure if Silverstripe supports such functions out of the box.

Comment: You have a few options as I see it. 1) only display safe options until the first time they save as I said above or 2) depending on the work that needs to be done you may be able to remove the offending statement. UnsavedRelationList is designed for your use case - adding items to a relationship on an unsaved object - so you may be able to pare things back enough or do them in the right order or 3) you might be able to hook into onBeforeWrite or, worst case subclass GridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest to implement some custom logic.

Comment: Not sure how to implement this so far but the $this->isInDB() does the trick for now.